# Word 2013 to OpenXML Converter

Tags: openxml

Is there any converter available for Word 2013?

I had used one tool 2 years ago, which was converting Word 2010 Document to OpenXML Tags and C# code.

I am not able to recall its name. We just need to create a Word document with the format we need and then use that tool to convert it in OpenXML tags.

Anyone has any idea about this kind of tool ? 
I have downloaded below tools, but they are not working for Word 2013.

1. Odf-AddInForWordSetup-en-1.0.exe
2. OdfAddInForOfficeSetup-en_4.0.5309.exe

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425). In the link that I provided above its features are described:

> Features include the ability to generate Open XML SDK 2.5 source code based on document content, compare source and target Open XML documents to reveal differences and to generate source code to create the target from the source, validate documents, and display documentation for the Open XML SDK 2.5 Classes, the ECMA376v1 standard, and the Microsoft Office implementation notes.